# Verify account endpoint in loopback

Tags: mailgun, email-verification, loopback4

I am trying to implement verify account endpoint in loopback4 thorugh mailgun, since I am new in loopback4 and typescript in general, I am not sure if I am doing the right way. I want to retype the following code in the picture for loopback.I have already done with saving active flag in database and generating secretToken at signing up.

[image]

My code in loopback

```
@post('/users/verify')
  async verify(
    @requestBody(VerifyRequestBody) userData: User
  ): Promise<{ userData: object }> {
    try {
      const foundUser = await this.userRepository.findOne({
        where: {
          secretToken: userData.secretToken,
        }
      })
      if (!foundUser) {
        throw new HttpErrors.Forbidden(`No user found`)
      }

      foundUser.active = true;
      foundUser.secretToken = ''
      const savedUser = await this.userRepository.create(foundUser);

    } catch (err) {
      return err
    }
  }

 User model, I am using MongoDB

import { Entity, model, property } from '@loopback/repository';

@model({ settings: {} })
export class User extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'string',
    id: true,
  })
  id: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  email: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  password: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  firstName: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  lastName: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: false
  })
  secretToken: string;

  @property({
    type: 'boolean',
    required: false,
    default: false
  })
  active: boolean;

  @property.array(String)
  permissions: String[]


  constructor(data?: Partial<User>) {
    super(data);
  }
}

export interface UserRelations {
  // describe navigational properties here
}

export type UserWithRelations = User & UserRelations;
```

User repository

```
import { DefaultCrudRepository } from '@loopback/repository';
import { User, UserRelations } from '../models';
import { MongoDsDataSource } from '../datasources';
import { inject } from '@loopback/core';

export type Credentials = {
  email: string,
  password: string,
  active: boolean
}

export type Verify = {
  secretToken: string
}

export class UserRepository extends DefaultCrudRepository<
  User,
  typeof User.prototype.id,
  UserRelations
  > {
  constructor(@inject('datasources.mongoDS') dataSource: MongoDsDataSource) {
    super(User, dataSource);
  }
}
```

Comment: LB4 has a built-in [authentication](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Loopback-component-authentication.html) and [authorization](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Loopback-component-authorization.html), 
please refer to it.

Comment: Does it have an email verification feature like mailgun?

Comment: The answer is no .But I think it's better to put the auth logic of `mailgun.js` into the built-in authentication and authorization, and it has a lot of extension methods. For example: customize a strategy and then write the relevant logic inside, then you can use it with decorator.